# Bug Subscription instagram API with cURL

Tags: php, api, curl, instagram

Here is my code to subscribe/unsubscribe to an real time of Instagram API.
The unsubscribe works but not the subscribe. Im not really good with cUrl, I just have use this part of code from http://thegregthompson.com/instagram-real-time-api-php/ with some extra customization.

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/";

$ch = curl_init();
if (isset($_GET['unsubscribe']))
{
    echo "unsubscribe";
    $url .= "?client_id=" . $config['instagram']['client_id'] . "&client_secret=" .                   
    $config['instagram']['client_secret'] . "&id=" . $_GET['tag'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
}
else
{
    $attachment =  array(
        'client_id' => $config['instagram']['client_id'],
        'client_secret' => $config['instagram']['client_secret'],
        'object' => 'tag',
        'object_id' => $_GET['tag'],
        'aspect' => 'media',
        'verify_token' => $config['instagram']['verify_token'],
        'callback_url'=> 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/callback/endpoint.php'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($result);
?>
```

$config is correctly included.

I spent so much time to try to fix it but no way.
Can you please help me to make the subscription works ?

Ask me if you need more details.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, I wrote "Hi guys" in the first line but It doesnt appear, even after edition...

Comment: Maybe I'm just overlooking it, but where is subscribe in your code? I see unsubscribe, but not subscribe.

Comment: the subscribe is by default, if there is no 'unsubscribe' parameter

Comment: I dont have any error, even using curl_error after each curl function call

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I fixed it: I think we should set the CURLOPT_POST before CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Correct

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
```

Incorrect

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```